# Is it possible to enforce a controller method to work only for specific HTTP methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there was a way to make controller methods in rails available only for specific HTTP methods (GET, POST, etc.).

I guess I can create a filter to do that but it seems to me that it is something that is available out-of-the-box in rails.

Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html section 3.11.1. You can specify what method should be accepted for each route.